# @Override "Method..." after copying method's from another Project

Tags: android, overriding

I'm just trying like more and more times to copy and paste some methods from one mine project to another i also rewrited these method's but damn `@Override` is giving me error "`method does not override it's superclass`" and i can't get why it's giving this error while i've done all in the same way in the other project

Here is the Project from where i'm trying to copy the methods:

```
package com.example.igardini.gabscan;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cipherlab.barcode.*;
import com.cipherlab.barcodebase.*;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ReaderCallback {

    ReaderManager m_RM = null;
    EditText e1 = null;
    private ReaderCallback mReaderCallback = null;
    DataBaseHandler myDB;
    String searchKeyword = "";
    String result = "";
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        e1 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        m_RM = ReaderManager.InitInstance(getApplicationContext());
        mReaderCallback = this;

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(GeneralString.Intent_READERSERVICE_CONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(myDataReceiver, filter);

        myDB = new DataBaseHandler(this);

        myDB.deleteCodart();
        getHTMLCod();

    }





    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myDataReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver myDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(GeneralString.Intent_READERSERVICE_CONNECTED)) {

                if(mReaderCallback != null){
                    m_RM.SetReaderCallback(mReaderCallback);
                }

            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onDecodeComplete(final String arg0) throws RemoteException {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                e1.setText(arg0);
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(e1.getText().toString())) {
                    searchKeyword = e1.getText().toString();
                    result = myDB.dbRawSearch(searchKeyword);

                    if(result != null){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textView.setText(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder asBinder() {
        return null;
    }
```

While here is the other project where i'm trying to copy it :

```
package com.example.igardini.visualposmobile;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cipherlab.barcode.GeneralString;
import com.cipherlab.barcode.ReaderManager;
import com.cipherlab.barcodebase.ReaderCallback;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class cassa extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Item> items;
    ArrayList<ItemCassa> itemCassas;
    TextView price;
    double prezzo;
    ReaderManager m_RM = null;
    private ReaderCallback mReaderCallback = null;
    DataBaseHandler myDB;
    String searchKeyword = "";
    String result = "";
    private ExampleAdapter exampleAdapter;
    EditText editText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cassa);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextBar);

        itemCassas = new ArrayList<>();

        loadData();
        buildTopRecyclerView();
        buildRecyclerView();

        price = findViewById(R.id.priceText);

        m_RM = ReaderManager.InitInstance(getApplicationContext());
        mReaderCallback = (ReaderCallback) this;

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(GeneralString.Intent_READERSERVICE_CONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(myDataReceiver, filter);

        myDB = new DataBaseHandler(this);



    }










    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myDataReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver myDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(GeneralString.Intent_READERSERVICE_CONNECTED)) {

                if(mReaderCallback != null){
                    m_RM.SetReaderCallback(mReaderCallback);
                }

            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onDecodeComplete(final String arg0) throws RemoteException {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                editText.setText(arg0);
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())) {
                    searchKeyword = editText.getText().toString();
                    result = myDB.dbRawSearch(searchKeyword);

                    if(result != null){
                        Toast.makeText(cassa.this, result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      //  textView.setText(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder asBinder() {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you did not implement other `interfaces`

in this line, it's an example only

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener
```

Change it in your own project, from your other project

Comment: damn i really forgot to impelent ReaderCallBack thank you